# Cannot Install PIP Packages on W10

Tags: python, pip

I´ve tried all posible ways, uninstalling python and pip and reinstalling them, creating a virtual environment, changing the settings to "true", checking that my needed folders are in the PATH, checking the system/user priviligies to allow all. And yet, I am still getting this OSError that cannot connect while trying to collect the package, see in picture below, I have used all the ideas listed in: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-system-cannot-find-file-specified, but as I wrote before I cannot install new pip packages:
[image]

I tried all the ideas listed here and yet no result:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-winerror-2-system-cannot-find-file-specified
I want to be able to install pip packages